# Necessity of 'static' in methods that get parameters by reference

Tags: c#

I'm programming in C# about 2 months, and I've been noticing to the fact that the only way a method will get a parameter by reference is when the method sets as a static method, and I don't understand the reason behind this situation. As example, in C++ we could just send parameters by reference to any kind of method we wanted to.

Thanks ahead :)

I'm adding a very simple code for those who asked for:

```
public void f(ref int num)
{
    num++;
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 0;
    f(ref a);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.Read();
}
```

the error I get:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

now, I know that in C# almost everything that not int, string, double... and other built-in vars are send automatically by ref. I wonder why the method must be static in case of sending those vars by ref.

Comment: if you want to pass by reference, use the `ref` keyword

Comment: Sample of code that shows non-static method that can't get a parameter by reference would make your question better. Duplicate indeed answers question as posted, but there is a good chance that it is not the question you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: @M4N That duplicate has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: You could be confusing some notions, so maybe you should give an example, like Alexei suggests. A `static` method does *not* get a reference to `this` since it does not belong to a particular instance (occurrence) of the class. What does the code look like in C++ when you "send parameters by reference"?

Comment: sorry about the delay, I edited and added a simple code that demonstrate my question.

Answer (score 1):

> the only way a method will get a parameter by reference is when the method sets as a static method

That's incorrect. C# has a concept of [Reference Types and Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), where both are passed by value, but that value differs. For reference types, the value that gets passed is the reference itself, where for value types it's a copy of the value.

If you want a value type by reference, you can use the `ref` modifier in the methods signature:

```
public void M(ref int x)
```

Same goes for reference type, only for the fact that passing them by `ref` will pass the current reference pointing to the data structure, and won't create a copy of that reference.

Comment: sorry about the delay and thank you for your answare, I edited and added a very simple code that demonstrate my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use `f` because it's an instance method and the `Main` is a static one so you cannot call it from here without having an instance of the class that contains `f` (I guess `Program`).

You need to either create an instance of `Program`:

this is exaclty the same as what the error message says:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

so you create an object reference to `Program`:

```
class Program 
{
    public void f(ref int num)
    {
        num++;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 0;
        var p = new Program();
        p.f(ref a);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

or make the method static to be able to use it:

```
class Program 
{
    public static void f(ref int num)
    {
        num++;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 0;
        f(ref a); // is the same as: Program.f(ref a)
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The `ref` keyword has nothing to do with it. It's all about how you call the method - via an object reference or as a static one without an object reference. Neither is better then the other. It's a design decision and each serves different puposes.